# Android multiple webview with highcharts freezes UI thread

Tags: android, highcharts, webview

I am new to android development.I have requirement to display charts (I am using high charts). Charts can be 2, 4 or 6 based on user selection and this charts will be getting run time data. 
I have added TCP connection using Async Task to get data from IOT device and supply it to web view using javascript function.
I have added table layout and added Web view inside it based on user selection. For Samsung 5 mini, 2 charts are working fine but when I load 6 charts, charts are not painting any data. Looks like, UI thread freezes as data feed to charts in every 100 ms.

I tried all the options like

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null); 
view.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE); 
view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

But nothing works for me.

Do you know any better way to feed data to web view that should not freeze the web view in multiple web view case?

Comment: How do you load the JS libary by CDN? You know if you use Highchart for an app on Google Play that you will need a Commercial license.

Comment: Yes, I have a commercial license. I kept JS library under assets folder.

Comment: How big is your data in your charts?

Comment: Every 100 ms, I am sending data [x,y] to javascript.

Comment: How is it then 1000 values for one chart? Or even more?

Comment: Data is continuously feeding to chart and I am purging data every after 1 second so 10 values at any given time.

Comment: So if I understand you in the beginning there will not be much data. So the 6 charts will load. But after some time it's freezes

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Could you create a testable demo and provide Highcharts related code?

Comment: When I ran same code over bluetooth, it's working fine so I believe, issue is not with web view rendering but TCP socket connection. Am I on right path?